# How to let webpack dev server check whether the client is desktop or mobile and respond different htmls?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, config, webpack-dev-server

I'm writing a React app and it needs to adapt the desktop end and the mobile end. There're so many components in my app that I have to build a new page to send it to mobile devices. That is, the desktop and mobile browsers get different index `html`s when the user visit the same index url, eg `localhost:3000/`. So, at the code level, `index.html` is for desktop and `mobile_index.html` is for mobile.

I know how to rewrite url in `webpack dev server`, which is like this:

```
historyApiFallback: {
  disableDotRule: true,
  rewrites: [
    { from: /^\/admin/, to: '/admin.html' },
  ]
},
```

I also know how to check whether the client is desktop or mobile and send different `html`s to the client browser in Express code. But I don't know how to  config `webpack dev server` to do this.

Comment: What is different about the two index files? Are they more than just the usual `html>body>div#app` shell?

Comment: The two index html files (templates) are different. Of course, the main thing is that their bundles (js and css) are different.

Comment: @1252748 I'm sorry I don't understand your second question.